# run a specific gradle script in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I've written some custom gradle scripts for running user tests, and they're running fine with a command line invocation like.

```
./gradlew -b custom01.gradle
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to run these in Eclipse and it's a bit more complicated. When I set up a Run Configuration, it complains that the task isn't found in the project  .

Any suggestions on how to run a specific gradle file from within Eclipse ?

[image: run configuration]
[image: error console]

Comment: I would expect that `-b custom01.gradle` has to specified as argument, not as task (in your outdated Eclipse IDE in the tab _Arguments_, otherwise in the _Project settings_ tab).

Comment: thanks @howlger ... tried that as well and no luck. So far Eclipse doesn't want to cooperate. I may try installing Gradle in the project from Eclipse, rather than developing from the command line first.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please update your question with the current Eclipse or is this a retro computing thing? Running Gradle as _Run > External Tools_ should always work, but showing the execution in the _Console_ instead of _Gradle Executions_ view.

Comment: retro computing :)